# Firefox issue with <object>, jQuery toggle() and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-maps

Firefox is resetting the position of a Google Map embedded with the object tag.

If you look at this jsFiddle in Firefox, you'll see the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/8c4nu/

It works fine in Webkit browsers, but in Firefox the map doesn't display properly.